# How to get my texts of my body content start from a little upper?

Tags: css, dompdf

I am trying to generate pdf using Dompdf. I have the following script for the design of my generated pdf.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@page { margin: 180px 50px; }
#header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: -180px; right: 0px; height: 120px; background-color:  orange; text-align: center; }
#footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: -180px; right: 0px; height: 150px; background-color: lightblue; }
#footer .page:after { content: counter(page, upper-roman); }
</style>

<body>
      <div id=\"header\">

     <h1>Charlie Sheen</h1>
     </div>

      Hi, This is Charlie Sheen <br>

    <p> Winning </p>
   <p> Winning </p>
  <p> Winning </p>
   <p> Winning </p>
    <p> Winning </p>
     <p> Winning </p>
      <p> Winning </p>

   <div id=\"footer\">
 <p class=\"page\">Page </p>
 </div>
 <div id=\"content\">
 <p>the first page</p>
 <p style=\"page-break-before: always;\">the second page</p>
 </div>                  

 </body>
</html>
```

[image]

When I generate the PDF it looks like the image above. Now my problem is I want my content to start from a little upper than it starts from now. If you notice the image above there is a sentence "Hi, this is charlie Sheen"... I want this to start from a little upper. I have tried to add the following code inside the style but it doesn't work:

```
#content { position: fixed; margin-top: 0px;}
```

Would you please kindly help me to get the content start from a little upper?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pushing the body in 180px from the top and bottom of the document  with `@page { margin: 180px 50px; }`. However, the height of your header is only 120px. So there will naturally be 60px of space between your header and body content. You should either increase the size of your header or decrease the `@page` margins.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @page { margin: 120px 50px; }
        #header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: -120px; right: 0px; height: 120px; background-color:  orange; text-align: center; }
        #footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: -120px; right: 0px; height: 150px; background-color: lightblue; }
        #footer .page:after { content: counter(page, upper-roman); }
    </style>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Charlie Sheen</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p class="page">Page </p>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>Winning!</p>
        <p style="page-break-before: always;">Winning!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Your original code, cleaned up a bit.)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the margin on the `#content` will not make a difference because `#content` is way down the page.

I would consider wrapping the first sentence in `p` tags, like so

`<p>Hi, This is Charlie Sheen</p>`

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I havetried <p>Hi, This is Charlie Sheen</p> but still no luck. I have also tried removing the texts from below the header div and put <p>Hi, This is Charlie Sheen</p> inside content div.. but it is not working too. could you please tell me how to solve this?